# The following ArgumentError was thrown building Home(dirty, state: _HomeState#75cb9):

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I have set up a Login page using Firebase Authentication

I have implemented a `_submit()` function in my code which logs in a user using the `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` and a seperate `googleSignIn()` method to login with google

but when I try to Log in using `_submit()` I get this error

`The following ArgumentError was thrown building Home(dirty, state: _HomeState#75cb9)`

here is my `_submit()` method

```
 _submit() async {
final isValid = _key.currentState.validate();
if (isValid) {
  _key.currentState.save();
  EasyLoading.show(status: "Please Wait...\n" + "Loggin in with \n");
  try {
    UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);
    User currentUser = auth.currentUser;
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

    print(userCredential);
    EasyLoading.dismiss();
    EasyLoading.showSuccess("Welcome back");

    Navigator.of(context)
        .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
        
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    EasyLoading.dismiss();
    if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
      Alert(
        context: context,
        style: AlertStyle(
          backgroundColor: bgcolor,
          titleStyle: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'valorant',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.white),
          descStyle: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'valorant', fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),
        ),
        type: AlertType.error,
        title: "Account Was Not Found !!",
        desc: "the email id entered does not exist ",
        buttons: [
          DialogButton(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Text(
              "Create Account",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontFamily: 'Valorant'),
            ),
            onPressed: () async {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              Navigator.of(context)
                  .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUP()));
            },
            width: 200,
          )
        ],
      ).show();
      print('No user found for that email.');
    } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
      print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
    }
  }
  }
 }
```

The class where the user sould go looks like this

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
const Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
bool isLoggedIn = true;
FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
User _user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {


void signout() async {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  setState(() {
    isLoggedIn = false;
  });
  Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
    Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignIN()),
        (route) => false);
  });
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  auth.authStateChanges().listen((user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print("no user Logged In");
      return isLoggedIn = false;
    } else {
      print(user.displayName + " is signed in ");

      return isLoggedIn = true;
    }
  });
}

return isLoggedIn
    ? Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("HI " + _user.displayName),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: signout,
            child: Text("Log Out"),
          ),
        ),
      )
    : Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text("NO USER LOGGED IN"),
        ),
      );
   }
 }
```

The Error I get is

```
The relevant error-causing widget was
Home                                           lib\Authentication\signin.dart:59
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _StringBase.+ (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:272:57)
#1      _HomeState.build                       package:myapp/home/Home.dart:62
#2      StatefulElement.build                  package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4775
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild        package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4658
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild
```

I have a google sign in function which takes me to the home page without any issue
but when using email id and password I face this error

my google sign in method is:

```
 signInWithGoogle() async {
EasyLoading.show(
    status: "Please Wait...", maskType: EasyLoadingMaskType.black);

GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
    await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
  accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
  idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
);

UserCredential userCredential = await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
user = userCredential.user;
assert(!user.isAnonymous);
assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

User currentUser = auth.currentUser;
assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
EasyLoading.dismiss();
EasyLoading.showSuccess("Welcome Back !!",
    maskType: EasyLoadingMaskType.black, duration: Duration(seconds: 3));

Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()), (route) => false);

print(user.displayName);
print(user.email);
}
```

[image: this is login using email and password]

this leads to

[image: the error I get]

where as

[image: using google sign in]

no issue
[image]

Comment: What's on line 59 of your`signin.dart` file?

Comment: `return isLoggedIn` see this on the code i provided

Comment: Could you post the full `signin.dart` file?

Comment: @VictorEronmosele her is the link to my signin.dart file

Comment: @VictorEronmosele here is the link to signin.dart [link](https://github.com/Somsubro-Banerjee/ggwp/blob/main/lib/Authentication/signin.dart)

Answer (score 0):

The `initState` method and the `signOut` method should be outside your `build` method.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  ...

  void signout() async {
    ...
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    ...
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }
}
```